# rangedummarizedexperiment for deseq2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to use the DESeq2 package in R for differential gene expression, but I'm having trouble creating the required RangedSummarizedExperiment object from my input data.  I have found several tutorials and vignettes for doing this, but they all seem to apply to a raw data set that is different from mine.  My data has gene names as row names and patient id as column names, and the data is simply integer count data.  There has to be a simple way to create the RangedSummarizedExperiment object from this type of input data, but I haven't yet found a way.  Can anybody help?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your data looks like? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . And please make your question title clearer - see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem understanding how to use this data structure. I eventually managed to do without it by using `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix`. You can see an example in the first code block of [Modify r object with rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42157335/1878788) (this code is pure R, rpy2 stuff comes after). In this example, I have genes as rows and samples as columns, so it is likely you will be able to adopt the same approach.